# Python global variable insanity

Tags: python

You have three files: main.py, second.py, and common.py

common.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
GLOBAL_ONE = "Frank"
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from common import *
from second import secondTest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global GLOBAL_ONE
    print GLOBAL_ONE #Prints "Frank"
    GLOBAL_ONE = "Bob"
    print GLOBAL_ONE #Prints "Bob"

    secondTest()

    print GLOBAL_ONE #Prints "Bob"
```

second.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from common import *

def secondTest():
    global GLOBAL_ONE
    print GLOBAL_ONE #Prints "Frank"
```

Why does secondTest not use the global variables of its calling program?  What is the point of calling something 'global' if, in fact, it is not!?

What am I missing in order to get secondTest (or any external function I call from main) to recognize and use the correct variables?

Comment: read about scopes and namespaces in Python http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Answer (score 11):

`global` means global for this module, not for whole program. When you do

```
from lala import *
```

you add all definitions of `lala` as *locals* to this *module*.

So in your case you get two copies of `GLOBAL_ONE`

Comment: If that is true, how do I access the second copy of GLOBAL_ONE?  What is the magical trick that I am missing?  (If you use the python debugger, you can see that the object IDs change: when you first print GLOBAL_ONE, after you assign it in main(), when you access it in secondTest, and then back to the second ID when you print it a second time in main().)

Comment: No way if you don't want to change anything. Either use solution proposed by @PreludeAndFugue or change your architecture to the better one like others suggest.

Answer (score 5):

The first and obvious question is *why?*

There are a few situations in which global variables are necessary/useful, but those are indeed few.

Your issue is with namespaces. When you import common into second.py, `GLOBAL_ONE` comes from that namespace. When you import secondTest it still references `GLOBAL_ONE` from common.py.

Your real issue, however, is with design. I can't think of a single logical *good* reason to implement a global variable this way. Global variables are a tricky business in Python because there's no such thing as a constant variable. However, convention is that when you want to keep something constant in Python you name it `WITH_ALL_CAPS`. Ergo:

```
somevar = MY_GLOBAL_VAR  # good!
MY_GLOBAL_VAR = somevar  # What? You "can't" assign to a constant! Bad!
```

There are plenty of reasons that doing something like this:

```
earth = 6e24
def badfunction():
    global earth
    earth += 1e5
print '%.2e' % earth
```

is *terrible.*

Of course if you're just doing this as an exercise in understanding namespaces and the `global` call, carry on.

If not, some of the reasons that global variables are A Bad Thing™ are:

- Namespace pollution
- Functional integration - you want your functions to be compartmentalized
- Functional side effects - what happens when you write a function that modifies the global variable `balance` and either you or someone else is reusing your function and don't take that into account? If you were calculating account balance, all of the sudden you either have too much, or not enough. Bugs like this are difficult to find.

If you have a function that needs a value, you should pass it that value as a parameter, unless you have a really good reason otherwise. One reason would be having a global of PI - depending on your precision needs you may want it to be `3.14`, or you may want it `3.14159265`... but that is *one* case where a global makes sense. There are probably only a handful or two of real-world cases that can use globals properly. One of the cases are constants in game programming. It's easier to import pygame.locals and use KP_UP than remember the integer value responding to that event. These are *exceptions* to the rule.

And (at least in pygame) these constants are stored in a separate file - just for the constants. Any module that needs those constants will import said constants.

When you program, you write functions to break your problem up into manageable chunks. Preferably a function should do *one* thing, and have no side effects. That means a function such as *calculatetime()* should calculate the time. It probably shouldn't go reading a file that contains the time, and forbid that it should do something like *write* the time somewhere. It can *return* the time, and take parameters if it needs them - both of these are good, acceptable things for functions to do. Functions are a sort of contract between you (the programmer of the function) and anyone (including you) who uses the function. Accessing *and changing* global variables are a violation of that contract because the function can modify the outside data in ways that are not defined or expected. When I use that `calculatetime()` function, I expect that it will calculate the time and probably return it, not modify the global variable time which responds to the module time that I just imported.

Modifying global variables break the contract and the logical distinction between actions that your program takes. They can introduce bugs into your program. They make it hard to upgrade and modify functions. When you use globals as variables instead of constant, [death awaits you with sharp pointy teeth!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071853/quotes?qt0470611)

Comment: I am confused by your suggestion to change the design; please enumerate how keeping a global variable in a file called 'globals.py' is any different than my placing it in a file called 'common.py'?  According to a few other answers I have seen here (I do not have handy links, please forgive me that), my solution is precisely what is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the results of the following to yours. When you use the correct namespaces you will get the results you expect.

common.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
GLOBAL_ONE = "Frank"
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from second import secondTest
import common

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print common.GLOBAL_ONE # Prints "Frank"
    common.GLOBAL_ONE = "Bob"
    print common.GLOBAL_ONE # Prints "Bob"

    secondTest()

    print common.GLOBAL_ONE # Prints "Bob"
```

second.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import common

def secondTest():
    print common.GLOBAL_ONE # Prints "Bob"
```

Comment: This does and does not work.  Well, let me clarify - this will allow secondTest to "see" GLOBAL_ONE.  However, in the actual code file (which is far more complex than my examples), both main.py and common.py hold far more information in them than these simple example files; I certainly do not believe that concatenating "common." on to the front of every single variable or function that I call, every single time I use them, is a great answer.  In fact, it seems like a badly thought-out kludge on the part of Python.  (If that is my only option, well, there we go, I guess I have to use it.)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you should do things this way. This is an example to compare with your's. J.F.Sebastian's comment to your question is what you should do. I don't think there is a problem with Python. Once you understand scopes and namespaces you will be in a better position to redesign your code to work more effectively in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first say that I agree with everybody else who answered before saying that this is probably *not* what you want to do. But in case you are really sure this is the way to go you can do the following. Instead of defining `GLOBAL_ONE` as a string in `common.py`, define it as a list, that is, `GLOBAL_ONE = ["Frank"]`. Then, you read and modify `GLOBAL_ONE[0]` instead of `GLOBAL_ONE` and everything works the way you want. Note that I do not think that this is good style and there are probably better ways to achieve what you really want.

Comment: This seems like it might work - I have not tried it yet - so thank you.  Why, however, should this work differently than any other variable?  Is it due to a difference in handling different object types?

Comment: Strings are immutable in python.

Comment: @Ankh: No, it's because instead of assigning a new value to the global variable, you're just modifying something about the value it already holds: the list, and particularly the value it contains.