# Global variable is not updating in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I have 3 files.

globalVar.py

```
global m_pTest
m_pTest = None
```

FileOne.py

```
import globalVar
import fileTwo

m_pTest = Class.getOutput() # Value is assigne
fileTwo.fun()
#Do anything
```

fileTwo.py

```
 import globalVar

 def fun():
    intVal = m_pTest.getInt()   # int value from m_pTest object
    print intVal
```

This is my short program sample when i run this it gives error in fileTwo.py in fun()

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getInt'
```

Can someone explain what is wrong in this code ?
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python global variable insanity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119287/python-global-variable-insanity)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is there any option to avoid global i am using so many global variables

Comment: This isn't your actual code right?  Running it will 1) get an error due to `Class` not being defined, and 2) even when I create my own object for `Class`, `fun` throws a NameError not an AttributeError.

Comment: @DigviJayPatil globals (module globals that is) are fine as long as they are considered as (pseudo) constants. Now when you have to share variables between functions / methods, the usual solutions are 1. using classes (so the methods can share the instance's state), 2. passing variables to functions/methods, 3. returning values from functions / methods. That's nothing new, really...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Can you give me some example it above problem context so that i can accept your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`global m_pTest` doesn’t make a variable magically global; instead it sets the name `m_pTest` in the *current scope* to refer to a global variable (from outer scope). So placing it in `globalVar.py` does basically nothing.

If you wanted to import only the variable, you could use the following:

```
from globalVar import m_pTest
```

However, when setting `m_pTest` to a different value, you will not affect the original object that was created in `globalVar.py` so the change isn’t seen elsewhere.

Instead, you have to import `globalVar` as normal, and then refer to `m_pTest` as a member of that module:

```
import globalVar

# reading
print(globalVar.m_pTest)

# setting
globalVar.m_pTest = 123
```

Comment: Then how could i get value in fileTwo.py those are set in fileOne.py

Answer (score 4):

Why using a global at all ?

```
# FileOne.py
import fileTwo

value = Class.getOutput() 
fileTwo.fun(value)
#Do anything

# fileTwo.py
def fun(value):
    intVal = value.getInt()   
    print intVal
```