# Python - from M import x then assigning to x does not pass new value back to M

Tags: python, python-module

The following code does what I would expect:

```
# test3.py
import test2

print('test3 started, test2.x={0}'.format(test2.x))

def modit():
    print('test3 setting x=4')
    test2.x = 4
```

If other modules have imported `test2`, subsequent references to `test2.x` give the value 4.

If instead, I use:

```
# test4.py

from test2 import x

print('test4 started, test2.x={0}'.format(x))

def modit():
    global x
    print('test4 setting x=4')
    x = 4
```

the new value is not passed back to `test2`. (I'm attaching all the code and output to confirm this below).

I've tried searching here and elsewhere for an explanation without luck. Most comments about `from M import x` *vs* plain `import M` etc. are about *what* is imported, not the nature of the connection.

I'd like to understand *why* the behaviour is different.

....

The rest of the code & output for the version that does not work:

```
# test1.py main module

import test2
print('test2 imported, test2.x={0}'.format(test2.x))

import test4
test4.modit()  # will change 'x'
print('* test1 now has  test2.x={0}'.format(test2.x))
```

...

```
# test2.py
x = 1
```

...

```
# test4.py

from test2 import x

print('test4 started, test2.x={0}'.format(x))

def modit():
    global x
    print('test4 setting x=4')
    x = 4
```

Result:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
test2 imported, test2.x=1
test4 started, test2.x=1
test4 setting x=4
* test1 now has  test2.x=1
```

Using the 'correct' version, given above (test3.py), gives the expected result

```
>>> 
test2 imported, test2.x=1
test3 started, test2.x=1
test3 setting x=4
* test1 now has  test2.x=4
>>>
```

Comment: Its only global at the module level, it doesn't get propagated up to the original module.

Comment: `x` is a name, a label for an object. Assigning to it doesn't change the object, only what the label points to.

Answer (score 1):

Importing in the style of `from x import y` imports the name `y` into your current module's namespace. You should think of it as working with a copy of `y` and not the actual `y`.

Here is an example of what is happening

## one.py

```
class x(object):
    prop = 'old'
```

## two.py

```
from one import x
x.prop = 'new'
```

## Example

```
>>> from one import x
>>> x
<class 'one.x'>
```

`x` is a name in the current scope that points to `one.x`.

```
>>> x.prop
'old'
```

The value of `x.prop` (from `one.x.prop`) is `'old'`

```
>>> import two
>>> x.prop
'new'
>>> x
<class 'one.x'>
```

Module `two` changes a property of `x` but the name `x` still points to `one.x`. This means that my `x` and the `x` in `two` are pointing to the same object so they both show the modified `x.prop`.

Now we reassign `x` to an `int`.

```
>>> x = 3
>>> two.x
<class 'one.x'>
>>> x
3
```

The value that `x` points to in `two` remains unchanged because we only changed our local name `x`.

Comment: Minor correction "reference to `y`", not copy. If the attributes of the imported thing are changed by the importer, the original object is changed to, but if they reassign the name itself to something else, then the link is lost.

Comment: The correction from @ShadowRanger is not that minor. I think it really deserves to be included in the answer itself. I would have upvoted if it had been, and was about to downvote without it.

Comment: I said you should **think** of it as working with a copy, not that is **was** a copy. You could change attributes of `x` because the name `x` is still pointing to the original object. If you change `x`, you are just pointing the name `x` at a new object. I can see how my simplification could be misleading.

Comment: Reading through this Shadow Rangers comment seems to me the most succint explanation of whats happened.   x as attribute of the imported module versus object in its own right.

Answer (score -1):

riotburn has already given the correct answer. For completeness I just dedicate it an own answer.

If you import x of module test2.py and change it in test4.py, this change is only visible in module test4.py because the imported x and its change is, because of the import, a local in the test4.py module.

To use a value of a module A, change this value in another module B and make this change visible in the module A, you have to import the whole module A and reference the value like you did in test3.py

This topic was also discussed in this post:
[Global variable is not updating in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392157/global-variable-is-not-updating-in-python)